Losing connection when connecting br-ex to bond - openstack
I want to configure openstack on a bond with a private static IP address and I also connect to the server through the same bond. I realized as soon as I connect the bond to br-ex I get disconnected from the server (server cannot ping its gateway) and br-ex state goes down, when I connect it to the bond by the following command:
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br-ex bond0
and when I try to bring the bridge br-ex back up, the bond is automatically deleted from the ports.
this is the configuration of bridges before adding the bond port:
#ovs-vsctl show
    Manager "ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1"
        is_connected: true
    Bridge br-ex
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        datapath_type: system
        Port phy-br-ex
            Interface phy-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=int-br-ex}
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
    Bridge br-int
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        datapath_type: system
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
        Port "tapf556c-c7"
            tag: 1
            Interface "tapf556c-c7"
                type: internal
        Port "tapd2980-19"
            tag: 4095
            Interface "tapd2980-19"
                type: internal
        Port "qr-8ea26-da"
            tag: 4095
            Interface "qr-8ea26-da"
                type: internal
        Port "tap89cc3-c0"
            tag: 2
            Interface "tap89cc3-c0"
                type: internal
        Port int-br-ex
            Interface int-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=phy-br-ex}
    ovs_version: "2.12.0"

any idea why this happens and what is the solution?
